# Scraping pages with multiple parts with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this [site](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/michael-frey/gemeinsameSpiele/spieler/147043) for a complete list of the teammates. I know how to do that with beautifoulsoup for the first page, but the results are broken in a lot of pages. Is there a way to scrape all of the parts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/yvon-mvogo/profil/spieler/147051

https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/steve-von-bergen/profil/spieler/4793

https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/scott-sutter/profil/spieler/34520

Above given are some links to the player profiles. You can open the page in BeautifulSoup and parse it to get all the links in it. Write a regular expression after to filter out only the links that satisfy the above pattern and write another function to extact information from profile pages

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    m = re.search('/[a-z\-]+/profil/spieler/[0-9]+', a['href'])
    if m:
        found = m.group(0)
        print(found)
```

#### Output

> /michael-frey/profil/spieler/147043
>   /yvon-mvogo/profil/spieler/147051
>   /scott-sutter/profil/spieler/34520
>   /leonardo-bertone/profil/spieler/194975
>   /steve-von-bergen/profil/spieler/4793
>   /alain-nef/profil/spieler/4945
>   /raphael-nuzzolo/profil/spieler/32574
>   /marco-wolfli/profil/spieler/4860
>   
> /moreno-costanzo/profil/spieler/41207
>   
> /jan-lecjaks/profil/spieler/62854
>   
> /alain-rochat/profil/spieler/4843
>   
> /christoph-spycher/profil/spieler/2871
>   
> /gonzalo-zarate/profil/spieler/52731
>   
> /christian-schneuwly/profil/spieler/52556
>   
> /yuya-kubo/profil/spieler/186260
>   
> /alexander-farnerud/profil/spieler/10255
>   
> /salim-khelifi/profil/spieler/147049
>   
> /alexander-gerndt/profil/spieler/45881
>   
> /adrian-winter/profil/spieler/59681
>   
> /victor-palsson/profil/spieler/97241
>   
> /milan-gajic/profil/spieler/46928
>   
> /dusan-veskovac/profil/spieler/28705
>   
> /marco-burki/profil/spieler/172192
>   
> /elsad-zverotic/profil/spieler/25542
>   
> /pa-modou/profil/spieler/66449
>   
> /yoric-ravet/profil/spieler/82461

You can loop through all the links and call a function that extracts the information that you require from the profile pages. Hope this helps

Use this link. I got it from inspecting the buttons

https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/michael-frey/gemeinsameSpiele/spieler/147043/ajax/yw2/page/1

You can change the number at the end to get each page

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I just want to get the names/links of the players listed in the site i linked. But there are so many that the site breaks them down in pages, like 15 per page. You press a button and it shows the next. My question is, how do i scrape all the pages/sets?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to do that in the answer

Comment: Thank you! Marked as solved. I know have a different problem though. Basically i want to create a tool that you enter the players name(exact) and it gives you a list of teammates, but i realised transfermarkt has random id's. I can't know the player's profile url if i just know his name. Do you know what i can do or should i post it as a different question?

Comment: You can build your own player database by crawling all the data from the site. But i'm sure you'll get better ideas if you post it as a different question